# File and Folder permissions in C# application

Tags: c#, security, permissions, file-permissions

My problem at the moment is that I need my program to able to write to a network drive with certain file and folder permissions, that don’t allow the current users to write, edit or delete directly on this drive as they keep messing up our directories. But I still need those permissions for my app. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: add permission from security tab to folder which you wants to access.

Comment: You need Impersonation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net run your app in user, which has access to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Adding EveryOne user with Full Permission to product folder at common application path will allow you to delete directly on this drive

```
var installationDir = new DirectoryInfo(strInstallationPath);       

DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = installationDir.GetAccessControl();
myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("EveryOne", FileSystemRights.FullControl, (InheritanceFlags)3, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
installationDir.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
FileInfo myFile = installationDir.GetFiles("abc.txt");
myFile.Delete();
```